# stopping time for non-martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$.

For each $x_i$, we have $x_i=1$ with probability $p$ and $x_i=-\lambda$ with probability $1-p$ with $\lambda>0$. Assume i.i.d.

Consider the stopping time $T$,

$T=inf\{N;S_N>0\ \text{or}\ S_N<K\}$ where $K<0$.

How to calculate $P(S_T>0)$ and $P(S_T<K)$?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you know the drill when $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$. Now you have a situation where $\mathbb{E}[X_i] \neq 0$. But, hey, what do you know about $Y_i =X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i]$? ...

Comment: Buy then you have an equation involving $P(S_T>0)$ and $E(T)$